# Angle brackets in Careers Profile "Background" link is rendered incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, profile-page

I tried to use the ascii-art heart (`<3`) in a link in my Careers profile, and found that it is parsed incorrectly in some cases. Interestingly, whilst this fails in the Background section, in the main profile it is rendered fine.

Try this example:

```
[I <3 Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)
```

This works fine on MSO ([I <3 Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)) and it works fine in the main Careers profile. But if you try it in the Background section, you'll get:

> [I

and it won't be linked.

Comment: Try to encode it: `[I &lt;3 Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)`

Comment: @ShaWiz: ha, that's a good idea. I'll do that if ♥ doesn't work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That definitely *is* a problem, just repro'd this on my own account. We'll get somebody to take a look at it. Thanks for the heads up

**EDIT**: I have a fix for this, but our source control server is undergoing maintenance. It'll go up when that's done.

Basically the `<` was triggering our user-input sanitization process before the markdown -> html conversion could take place. I reordered that process so that the conversion (which handles entity encoding) takes place before the sanitization.

Comment: No way – script injection on Stack Exchange. [I’m going to enjoy this while it lasts.](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/employer/202792)

Comment: Well, _that's_ definitely not good at all.

Comment: Although, on the other hand, it’s not as if many people can see that page :P

Comment: This will be fixed along with the original bug.

Comment: Heh heh, having fun with the buglet everyone? Thanks Ross.

Comment: Okay, the fix has been published!